# Java(FX): How can I edit the menu items of the standard mac os x menu bar?

Tags: java, macos, menu, javafx, native

I'm developing a Java(FX) application and like to change the title of my application in the standard menu item of every application (see the screenshot). I also want to set an own behavior for the About and Preferences menu items, but they arn't there.

[image: Screenshot: The standard menu item of TextWrangler]

I know, that this is possible in swing, but how it is possible with! JavaFX?

Comment: I don't think there's API for this i once thought about porting native code from SWT where there is API for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [NSMenuFX](https://github.com/codecentric/NSMenuFX) to do this. Here is an example on how to create an `About` menu:

```
NSMenuBarAdapter adapter = new NSMenuBarAdapter();

// Get the default menu bar as JavaFX object
MenuBar menuBar = adapter.getMenuBar();

// Create a new menu item
MenuItem about = new MenuItem("About");

about.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
  @Override
  public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
    // Open a new JavaFX dialog
  }
});

// Add the menu item as first element to the application menu
menuBar.getMenus().get(0).getItems().add(0, about);

// Update the menu bar
adapter.setMenuBar(menuBar);
```